# How to get my icon to display in my Firefox Addon?

Tags: firefox-addon

I have created an Addon and uploaded it to addons.mozilla.org and it works ok, but it's displaying a default icon instead of my icon. I don't get this problem with Chrome.

My `manifest.json` file looks like:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Handcash handle converter",
  "version": "1.4",

  "description": "Get a receiving address for a Handcash $handle",
  "icons": {
    "48": "handcash48.png",
    "64": "handcash64.png",
    "128": "handcash128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Handcash handle converter",
    "default_popup": "./popup/popup.html"
  },
  "homepage_url": "https://www.handcash.io",
  "short_name": "HandcashConv",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://api.moneybutton.com ; object-src 'self'",  

  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "clipboardWrite"
  ]
}
```

I tried putting the icons in their own directory and at the root of the extension but no joy. The extension looks like this in Firefox:

[image: icon]

Full source code in case you're interested: https://github.com/markallisongit/handcash-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `icons` entry of the `manifest.json` refers to icons used in the addon listing, addon management page, etc. What you want here is to set the icon of the `browserAction` button in the toolbar. If you have a look at the [browser_action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/browser_action) page on the MDN, you'll notice a `default_icon` setting, and I believe this is what you're looking for :

> Use this to specify one or more icons for the browser action. The icon
>   is shown in the browser toolbar by default.
>
> Icons are specified as URLs relative to the manifest.json file itself.
>
> You can specify a single icon file by supplying a string here:
>
> ```
> "default_icon": "path/to/geo.svg"
> ```
>
> To specify multiple icons in different sizes, specify an object here.
>   The name of each property is the icon's height in pixels, and must be
>   convertible to an integer. The value is the URL. For example:
>
> ```
> "default_icon": {
>       "16": "path/to/geo-16.png",
>       "32": "path/to/geo-32.png"
>     }
> ```

In the end, you should update your manifest.json so that it includes this `default_icon` setting, something like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Handcash handle converter",

  ...

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Handcash handle converter",
    "default_popup": "./popup/popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "48": "handcash48.png",
      "64": "handcash64.png",
      "128": "handcash128.png"
    }
  },

  ...
}
```